# How do I get a React App to use a refresh_token seamlessly for the user when the access_token expires?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0

I'm really unclear on how I write the code to use a refresh token within a React app I'm building. I should note that I am a self-confessed React N00B.

So by way of example, I have the following POST code:

```
fetch(`${apiUrls.domain}${apiUrls.postNewContainer}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    changeId: this.state.change,
                    containerName: this.state.containerName,
                    containerDescription: this.state.containerDescription,
                    startDateTime: this.state.startDateTime,
                    endDateTime: this.state.endDateTime
                })
            })
```

In the event that the time has expired on the 60 minute access_token, how do I get it to trigger the sending of an authentication request (as below):

```
        var details = {
            username: this.props.email,
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
        }
        
        var signInBody = [];
        for (var property in details) {
            var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
            var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
            signInBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
        }
        signInBody = signInBody.join('&');
        
        fetch(`${apiUrls.domain}${apiUrls.postToken}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': webAppAuth.token
            },
            body: signInBody
        })
        .then(results => 
            results.json()
            )
        .then(results => {
            let accessToken = results.access_token
            let expiresIn = results.expires_in
            let expiryTime = Date.now() + (results.expires_in * 1000)
            let refreshToken = results.refresh_token
            if (expiresIn > 0) {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refreshToken);
                localStorage.setItem('expires_in', expiresIn)
                localStorage.setItem('expiry_time', expiryTime);
            };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
```

that will issue me a new access_token, and then get the original fetch request to run with the new access_token, all seamlessly for the end user?

I'm doing this on my own, learning as I go, with no-one else to reach out to other than Google and StackOverflow. Your help would be really appreciated, as all I seem to be able to find is the 'written logic flow' as opposed to how it actually looks in code.

Thank you in advance,
Andy

NB: if it helps, I have the 'expiryTime' saved in localStorage, so can cross-reference this with Date.now() to see if the access_token has expired before using it. If I do use it, and it's expired, the API returns a '401 Unauthorized' message with the following body:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid token: access token has expired"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SAMPLE CODE**

I would aim to use a proven library for the SPA security code, since it can get tricky. Here is a [pretty complete implementation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts) from a ReactJS code sample of mine that uses the [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library.

**REFRESH TOKENS**

Looks like you are already sending the **refresh token grant** message correctly. Eventually the refresh token will expire and you will get an error with an **invalid_grant** error code, meaning the user session has expired and the user must be redirected to authenticate again.

**TRIGGERING A REDIRECT**

I usually do this in 2 stages to prevent error displays from flashing up:

- Throw an error with a known error code, such as **login_required**, that completes the API request, and which your error handling code knows to ignore
- Update the browser location with the Authorization Request URL, to trigger the user login redirect

**FURTHER INFO**

Here are a few links from a blog of mine that may be useful later, since token renewal can get a bit tricky in terms of the right balance between security, usability and reliability:

- [Getting Started with OIDC Client](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/28/basicspa-codingkeypoints/)
- [Token Renewal](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/)
- [React SPA Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/07/local-ui-setup/)

Comment: Thank you!

Just logged in to say that I *think* I resolved it by adding the following within the code block:

`expiry() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('expiry_time') - Date.now() < 1000) {
            return <RefreshToken />
        }
        else {
            return null
        }
    }`
and then <this.expiry> within the render. 

But, I'm going to have a good review of the above to see if there is a better way.

Thank you again.